# I want Create zip by shell exclude Path directories(/home/user/Desktop/zipfolder)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-10.04

Directory i want to compress

> /zipfolder

When i compressed. Its compressed with whole path

> (home/user/Desktop/zipfolder)

I just want to compress specific folder (zipfolder).

> I used zip -r filename.zip home/user/Desktop/* -x But its not working